# How to find the logical equivalent statement of $(P \lor Q) \lor (P \land R)$ without using truth table from given options.

Tags: logic

The options are

a)$(P \lor Q) \land (P \lor R)$

b)$(P \lor Q ) \land R $

c)$(P \lor Q) \land (P \land R)$

d)$(P \lor Q)$

e)$(P \land Q) \lor P$

So I was wondering if it is possible to find the logical equivalent without constructing their truth table and comparing.

Comment: Try using common rules for logic, I can highly recommend De Morgan rules: $A \land(B \lor C) = (A \land B) \lor (A \land C)$, same is true if you interchange $\land$ and $\lor $.

Comment: @LegNaiB, what you wrote are not De Morgan rules, but distributivity. De Morgan rules state $\neg (A\wedge B) = \neg A \vee \neg B$ and $\neg (A\vee B) = {\neg A} \wedge \neg B$.

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry. I meant distributivity but wrote De Morgan. De Morgan does not help in the above problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try using the algebraic notation consisting in replacing $\vee$ by addition and $\wedge$ by a product. Then you get
$$
(p + q) + pr = p + pr + q = p(1+r) + q = p +q
$$
since $1 + x = 1$ for all $x$.

Comment: wow that never crossed my mind.

Answer (score 1):

We have $P \wedge R \leq P \leq P \vee Q$ for any assignment of truth values to $P$, $Q$, and $R$, and so $(P \vee Q) \vee (P \wedge R) = P \vee Q$.